# ASP..NET: check if url is reachable or exists

Tags: asp.net

I have a function that check an URL if it is exists

```
private bool UrlExists(string url){
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request == null) return false;
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
catch (UriFormatException uriException)
{
    //Invalid Url
    Log.Error(this, uriException.Message);
    return false;
}
catch (WebException webException)
{
    //Unable to access url
    Log.Error(this, webException.Message);
    return false;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.Error(this, ex.Message);
    return false;
}}
```

But it did not work as my expectation.

Some URLs work such as stackoverflow, some local urls,.. 
But for special site that I had deployed to staging, I can open it but the method give exception as `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.`

What are wrong in my method? What's the best solution for testing an URL is exists?

p.s: I also try to do another method that check URL is reachable, but it did not work for that URL as well

```
private async Task<bool> UrlIsReachable(string url){
try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var httpRequestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMsg);
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(this, ex.Message);
    return false;
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are the only urls not working local urls?

Comment: if you got a 500, the URL exists, the problem is that whatever is processing that URL at the remote side threw an error instead of returning the page. (Very) basically, unless you get a 404 (Not Found) error then the URL probably exists. There might be some subtleties if you get other responses (e.g. redirects) - it's up to you whether you define a redirected URL as "existing" or not. Likewise if you get an authentication challenge (e.g. 401), unless you can authenticate and then make another request, you can't be sure if the URL behind it exists or not.

Comment: Might be useful to have a look through the list of possible response codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and decide how you want to handle and categorise each possibility.

Comment: If I try the request http://domain -> it does not work.
But if I try for a specified url http://domain/document/1 -> it works

Comment: I think your method is fine...just dont look for 200 return code. Instead check if the return code is not 404

Comment: Thank @ADyson and everyone. So that might the remote side issue.